# how to make this htacess rewrite rule stop failing because of final parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have this URL rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(send-your-request.*)$ / [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

it should basically just remove "/send-your-request" from the the URL (i.e. rewrite it with query string parameters from the domain i.e.

```
http://example.com/send-your-request/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test
```

is rewritten to:

```
http://example.com/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test
```

In that cases it works, but if I add the last parameter, it stops working

```
http://example.com/send-your-request/?a_aid=rocketnews24&pname=just%20a%20test&plink=http%3A%2F%2Fradio-eva.jp%2Fshop%2Fproducts%2Fdetail.php%3Fproduct_id%3D82
```

Can anyone tell me a better rewrite rule that can handle all the query string parameters?

**EDIT**
here are my other rules, but I have "L" on the first one, so it should stop processing right?

```
RewriteRule ^(send-your-request.*)$ / [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /products http://whiterabbitexpress.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1s=%2 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/?$ / [NC,QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Remove the QSA switch from your rules - as I understand the logic, you don't need to process query string. The query string appended in the regexp is the cause of your problem

Comment: @KamilŠrot I took the qsa off, but the behavior is same. If the final parameter is `plink=123` it works (redirects), but if the final param is a url, it will not redirect (404 on my site)... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it was a Mod_security rule designed to protect against injection. Working to get it disabled now.

SecRule REQUEST_URI "=(?:ogg|gopher|data|php|zlib|(?:ht|f)tps?)://" \
          "capture,id:340165,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,t:replaceNulls,t:compressWhiteSpace,t:lowercase,rev:275,severity:2,msg:'Atomicorp.com UNSUPPORTED DELAYED Rules: Uniencoded possible Remote File Injection attempt in URI (AE)',logdata:'%{MATCHED_VAR}'"